# Can't login given Windows authentication and an AD group authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've read up on Authentication and Authorization for a web application, but I can't figure out what's going on with this. In the application's web.config file it shows Windows authentication, and the authorization allows the role "DL_RPM_Commissions_Partners". We have users who are in that role, however, who cannot get in to the application. The system keeps prompting them for their credentials, not accepting the correct ones.

I realize this isn't a lot of detail for you, but I don't know what else to tell you up front. Please feel free to ask me questions that are pertinent to the problem, and I'll do my best to answer them. I need to get this resolved as soon as possible since legitimate users are being locked out of an essential application.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the Authorization tag look like in the web.config file?  Is IIS configured for Windows Authentication (IIS should have Anonymous/Basic auth disabled and Windows Auth enabled), and is the Authentication mode set to Windows in the web.config as well?

Comment: <location path="PartnerView.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="DL_RPM_Commissions_Partners" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

I don't have permissions to see IIS stuff on the server (sore subject). Yes, the Authentication mode is set to Windows in the web.config file. (Sorry about the formatting - can't figure out how to make it pretty.)

Comment: I'd have whoever is responsible for IIS check the Authorization settings for the IIS website.  If that is not configured for Windows auth, then users will be denied access.  Also, I ran into an issue once similar to what you are describing which required a reboot of the webserver (IISReset did not do the trick - full server reboot was necessary)

Comment: I'll see what I can find out, @DVK. Thanks for the suggestions.